# Else if statement not executing , its supposed to console.log the last statement in this case

Tags: if-statement

```
// Do I have to place parentheses somewhere in the last else if to prioritize?

const dolphinScore = 88 + 91 + 110 / 3;
console.log(dolphinScore);
const koalaScore = 88 + 91 + 110 / 3;
console.log(koalaScore);

//88 + 91 + 110 / 3

const minScore = 100;

if (dolphinScore > koalaScore && minScore) {
    console.log(`The dolphins win with a score ${dolphinScore}`)
} else if (koalaScore > dolphinScore && minScore) {
    console.log(`The koalas win with a score of ${koalaScore}`)
} else if (dolphinScore == koalaScore && >= minScore) {
    console.log("This is a draw, no one wins");
}
```

Expected the `else if` to execute but it isn't working go easy on me I'm re leaning the basics!

Else if statement not executing, it's supposed to console.log the last statement in this case but its acting as if the `(dolphinScore == koalaScore && >= minScore)` isn't true?

Comment: BTW, you probably mean `(88 + 91 + 110 )/ 3`, if you are wanting to calculate an average of the three scores.

Comment: Thank you Ken , that was going to be my next thing to try to figure out. I knew it wasnt executing right somewhere because it wasnt following the "PEMDAS" rule in my head.

Comment: Is any particular language supposed to give meaning to the code presented? Please tag!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies in this line:

```
if (dolphinScore > koalaScore && minScore)
```

It should be:

```
if (dolphinScore > koalaScore && dolphinsScore > minScore)
```

The `&&` operation must be between 2 boolean statement.

Comment: This works! I think i answered my own question below could you look into it to see if thats another proper way to solve the problem i was have? Thank you Salvia !

Answer (score -1):

Changed the constant variables `dophinsScore` & `koalaScore` to just regular declarations and it executed here's my new code that works,
could someone let me know if this is the proper way to solve this issue?

```
let dolphinScore = 88 + 91 + 110 / 3;
console.log(dolphinScore);
let koalaScore = 88 + 91 + 110 / 3;
console.log(koalaScore);

//88 + 91 + 110 / 3

const minScore = 100;


if (dolphinScore > koalaScore && minScore) {
    console.log(`The dolphins win with a score ${dolphinScore}`)
} else if (koalaScore > dolphinScore && minScore) {
    console.log(`The koalas win with a score of ${koalaScore}`)
} else if (dolphinScore == koalaScore || dolphinScore, koalaScore = minScore) {
    console.log("This is a draw, no one wins");
}
```

Comment: Please do not use *answer* to ask a new question.

Comment: No. I can't recognise this as the way to code the conditions of conditional statements in any language. Please revisit [Salvia rosmarinus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75467674/3789665) and your language reference material on *boolean expressions*.